# CXF Request Retry

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

I am using generated CXF service clients for soap end points. But as per integration there is a middleware for checking some custom http headers dynamically fetched from itself. Basically an API Gateway.

As per the product's behavior there are some background jobs and I do not want to fail those jobs because of the API Gateway parameters. thus I need to resend a request if it fails because of some parameters related to API Gateway expired. (I am not interested in changing the current service logic, but only a retry logic in case of some specific failures).

At first I though I can do this on the calling site (after getting the port from the service) but that's a bit lack of responsibility chain. This is an issue related to gateway. Not with the client logic.

So I am looking a way to retry request if it fails with specific 401 and 403 http codes on CXF Bus.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `RetryStrategy`. See https://cxf.apache.org/docs/failoverfeature.html

But after reading you description I'm unsure if you applied the right integration patterns in this case. Maybe changing the architecture would make more sense...